# adblock blocks links to social media

Tags: html, facebook, image, adblock

I the footer of a website I am developing we have a series of links to different social media sites that my client uses. On most systems all of our images loads; however, on my desktop most of the social media icons do not load.

the names of the images are as follows 'facebook.png', 'twitter.png' ect.

the reason I suspect adblock is because when looking at my network in the developer tools i get the error `(failed) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you have an additional filter list installed that blocks those images (e.g. "Remove social media buttons", "Fanboy's Social filters"). Note that, at least in Adblock Plus, such a filter list is not installed by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try renaming the image files, 'ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT' is most probably due to the Adblock filter picking up 'facebook', 'twitter', etc in the file names.